Prove $f(x) = x + 2e^{-a^2/2}(x\cosh(ax) - a\sinh(ax)) \ge 0$ for $0 \le x \le \frac{a}{2}$

I am trying to prove that
$$f(x) = x + 2e^{-a^2/2}(x\cosh(ax) - a\sinh(ax)) \ge 0$$ for $0 \le x \le \frac{a}{2}$.

From the plots that I have done this seems to be true. However, I have not been able to show this.
The first thing that I have tried is finding a lower bounding function $g$ for $f$ on $[0, \frac{a}{2}]$ for which it is clear that $g(x) \ge 0$ on $[0, \frac{a}{2}]$.
Since $f(0) = 0$ and $f(\frac{a}{2}) = \frac{3}{2}ae^{-\frac{a^2}{2}} > 0$, I have also tried analyzing the derivative $f'(x) = 1 + 2e^{-\frac{a^2}{2}}(ax\sinh(ax)-(a^2 - 1)\cosh(ax))$ to see whether I would be able to find something. If $0 \le a \le 1$ then $-(a^2 - 1) \ge 0$ and consequently $f'(x) \ge 0$, which implies that $f(x) \ge 0$. However, for $a > 1$ in general, I cannot seem to find the way to show this.
Which approach could I take for this proof?

Differentiating $f_a'(0)$ w.r.t. $a$, one finds that $f_a'(0) \geq f_{\sqrt 3}'(0) = 1 - 4e^{-\frac32}$ which is quite close to $0$ but still $> 0$ because $e^{-\frac32} \approx 0.22$. So, I don't know how this changes for other values of $x$ since it gets more complicated, but seeing how close this got to $0$, this could be tight enough that you'll really need to show that $f_a$ is positive rather than just the second term of the RHS, which is $f_a(x) - x$. But at least it confirms that $f_a(x) \geq 0$ on a neighbourhood of $0$ for all $a \geq 0$, so that's a start I suppose.

Why the "complex analysis" tag?

Some problems in real analysis can be solved through complex analysis. Since f(x) is holomorphic, I thought this could also be the case

An equivalent form is $g(x):=\frac12e^{a^2/2}+\cosh x-\frac{a^2}x\sinh x\ge0$ for $0<x\le\frac{a^2}2$.
The derivative $g'(x)=\left(1+\frac{a^2}{x^2}\right)\sinh x-\frac{a^2}x\cosh x$ is non-negative for all $a\le\sqrt3$ as $g'(x)<0$ iff $a^2>\frac{x^2}{x\coth x-1}$ and the RHS is always greater than $3$. As $g(0)=\frac12e^{a^2/2}+1-a^2>0$ for all $a$, this proves the inequality for $a\le\sqrt3$.
Herein, assume $a>\sqrt3$. The derivative $g'(x)$ is negative if $h(x):=\frac x{a^2}+\frac1x-\coth x<0$. To prove that $h(x)$ has exactly one positive root $x^*$, it is sufficient to prove that $h'(x)=\frac1{a^2}-\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{\sinh^2x}$ has exactly one positive root as $h(0)=0$ and $h(+\infty)=+\infty$. Indeed, $h''(x)=\frac2{x^3}\left(1-\frac{\cosh x}{(\sinh x/x)^3}\right)$ which is non-negative as a result of Lazarevic (1966). Since $h'(0)=\frac1{a^2}-\frac13<0$ and $h'(+\infty)=\frac1{a^2}>0$, the conclusion follows.
Thus $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing for $0<x<x^*$. The scenario $\frac{a^2}2\le x^*$ occurs when $h\left(\frac{a^2}2\right)\le0$; that is, for all $a\ge\sqrt{2a^*}$ where $a^*\approx1.797$ is the unique solution of $\coth a-\frac1a=\frac12$. In this interval, $g(x)\ge g\left(\frac{a^2}2\right)=\frac32e^{-a^2/2}>0$, so this proves the inequality for $a\ge\sqrt{2a^*}$.
In the interval $\sqrt3<a<\sqrt{2a^*}$, the hyperbolic Casa-Huygens inequality $\frac{\sinh x}x<\frac{2+\cosh x}3$ for all $x$ (Neuman and Sandor, 2010) yields $g(x)>\frac12e^{a^2/2}-\frac23a^2+\left(1-\frac{a^2}3\right)\cosh x$. It suffices to show that the RHS is positive at the endpoint $x=\frac{a^2}2$; that is, $q(\alpha):=\frac12e^\alpha-\frac{4\alpha}3+\left(1-\frac{2\alpha}3\right)\cosh\alpha>0$ for $\frac32<\alpha<a^*$ where $\alpha=\frac{a^2}2$. Now $6q'(\alpha)=(9-4\alpha)\sinh\alpha-\cosh\alpha-8<0$ for all $\alpha$ as $9-4\alpha-\frac8{\sinh\alpha}$ is negative. Thus $q(\alpha)$ is strictly decreasing, and since $a^*<1.8$, we have $q(\alpha)>q(1.8)>0$. This proves the inequality for $\sqrt3<a<\sqrt{2a^*}$, and hence completes the entire proof.

"Prove that $2024\frac{\sinh x}x-\cosh x\le\frac12e^{1012}$ for $0<x\le1012$" would be an unpleasant contest problem...

Note that we can write the hyperbolic functions as infinite series:
$$\cosh(ax) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ax)^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
$$\sinh(ax) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ax)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
Hence,
$$x\cosh(ax) - a\sinh(ax) = x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)!} - a \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n)!} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n+2}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
Combine terms into a single sum:
$$x\cosh(ax) - a\sinh(ax) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{a^{2n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n)!} - \frac{a^{2n+2}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \right)$$
Observe that
$$\frac{1}{(2n)!} = \frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)!}$$
so each term in the sum becomes
$$\frac{a^{2n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n)!} - \frac{a^{2n+2}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{a^{2n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\left( 2n+1 - a^2 \right)$$
Thus,
$$x\cosh(ax) - a\sinh(ax) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} (2n+1 - a^2)$$
Plugging this back into $f(x)$, we get
$$f(x) = x + 2e^{-a^2/2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} (2n+1 - a^2)$$
Because $x \ge 0$, each factor $\frac{a^{2n}x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ is non-negative, and the sign of each summand depends on $(2n+1 - a^2)$. For sufficiently large $n$, we have $2n+1 > a^2$, so all high-index terms in the sum are positive. In the range $0 \le x \le \frac{a}{2}$, we can show by comparing partial sums (or by bounding any finite number of "possibly negative" terms with the tail of the series) that the entire infinite series remains non-negative once combined with the extra $+ x$. Indeed, pick an index $N$ such that $2N+1 > a^2$. For $n \ge N$, the terms $(2n+1 - a^2)$ are strictly positive and hence add up to a non-negative contribution. For $0 \le n < N$, each term can be bounded below by taking $x \le \frac{a}{2}$ so that the front term $+ x$ plus the positive tail make the total sum non-negative. Thus,
$$f(x) \ge 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad 0 \le x \le \frac{a}{2}$$
and this argument holds for any $a > 0$ without resorting to a separate bounding function or splitting cases based on the value of $a$.

I think it should be $2n + 1 - a^2$ because you forgot a power of $a$ at some point, but otherwise this seems good!

@BrunoB: Thanks. I am 95 years old so not as sharp as I used to be.

I am trying to grasp the part where you state "for $0 \le n < N$, each term can be bounded below by taking $x \le \frac{a}{2}$ so that the front term $+x$ plus the positive tail make the total sum non-negative". Could you expand on that?

@BrunoB The first 70% of this answer is simply a verbose way of deriving a series representation of $f$. The rest of the answer (the most important part) offers no actual proof that $f$ is non-negative, only claiming that the positive part is larger than the negative part.

@TheSimpliFire I was waiting to see Raynard's response to OP's comment before saying anything. I wouldn't describe the series derivation as verbose myself, but I do agree that more should be said at the end.

Alternative solution.
If $x = 0$, true. In what follows, assume that $0 < x \le a/2$.
Multiplying both sides by $a \mathrm{e}^{a^2/2}$, the desired inequality is equivalent to
$$ax \mathrm{e}^{a^2/2} + 2ax \cosh ax - 2a^2 \sinh ax 
\ge 0. \tag{1}$$
Let $y := ax$ and $z := a^2/2$. To prove (1), it suffices to prove that, for all $0 < y \le z$,
$$y\mathrm{e}^{z} + 2y \cosh y - 4z \sinh y \ge 0. \tag{2}$$
Let $f(z) := y\mathrm{e}^{z} + 2y \cosh y - 4z \sinh y $.
We split into three cases.

Case 1. $y \ge 2$

We have $f'(z) = y\mathrm{e}^z - 4\sinh y \ge y\mathrm{e}^y - 4\sinh y > 0$ for all $z \ge y$. Also, $f(y) = y\mathrm{e}^{y} + 2y \cosh y - 4y \sinh y = 3y\mathrm{e}^{-y} \ge 0$. Thus, (2) is true.

Case 2. $0 < z \le 11/6$ and $0 < y \le 2$

Using $\mathrm{e}^z = \mathrm{e}^{\ln 4}\mathrm{e}^{z-\ln 4} \ge \mathrm{e}^{\ln 4} (1 + z - \ln 4)$, we have
\begin{align*}
 f(z) &\ge 4y (1 + z - \ln 4) + 2y\cosh y - 4z \sinh y \\
 &= 4y(1 - \ln 4) + 2y \cosh y - z (4\sinh y - 4y)\\
 &\ge 4y(1 - \ln 4) + 2y \cosh y - \frac{11}{6} (4\sinh y - 4y) \tag{3}\\
 &\ge 0 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
where we use $\sinh y \ge y$ in (3). (The proof of (4) is given at the end.) Thus, (2) is true.

Case 3. $z \ge 11/6$ and $0 < y \le 2$

Using $\mathrm{e}^z = \mathrm{e}^2\mathrm{e}^{z-2} \ge \mathrm{e}^2 (1 + z - 2)$, we have
\begin{align*}
 f(z) &\ge y\mathrm{e}^2(z - 1) + 2y\cosh y - 4z \sinh y \\
 &= - y\mathrm{e}^2 + 2y \cosh y + z (y\mathrm{e}^2 - 4\sinh y)\\
 &\ge - y\mathrm{e}^2 + 2y \cosh y + \frac{11}{6} (y\mathrm{e}^2 - 4\sinh y) \tag{5}\\
 &\ge 0 \tag{6}
\end{align*}
where we use $\frac{4\sinh y}{y} \le \frac{4\sinh 2}{2} < \mathrm{e}^2$ in (5). (The proof of (6) is given at the end.) Thus, (2) is true.
We are done.

Proof of (5) and (6):
It suffices to prove that, for all $0 < y < 2$,
$$\frac{191}{33}y + 2y\cosh y - \frac{22}{3}\sinh y \ge 0. $$
(Note: $(3) - (\frac{191}{33}y + 2y\cosh y - \frac{22}{3}\sinh y )
= (61/11 - 8\ln 2)y \ge 0$, and $(5)
- (\frac{191}{33}y + 2y\cosh y - \frac{22}{3}\sinh y) = (5\mathrm{e}^2/6 - 191/33)y \ge 0$.)
We have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{191}{33}y + 2y\cosh y - \frac{22}{3}\sinh y\\
 ={}& - (11/3 - y)\mathrm{e}^y + \frac{11/3 + y}{\mathrm{e}^y} + \frac{191}{33} y \\
 \ge{}& - (11/3 - y)N + \frac{11/3 + y}{N} + \frac{191}{33} y\\
 ={}& \frac{25y(-5y^6+648y^4-4656y^2+8640)}{-33y^6 + 792y^4 - 23760y^2 + 475200}\\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
where we use $\mathrm{e}^y \le N := 
\frac{y^3 + 12y^2 + 60y + 120}{-y^3 + 12y^2 - 60y + 120}$ on $[0, 2]$ (the proof is smooth by calculus).
We are done.
